# Promise data not rendering on route state changes - UI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

For example, home route shows home feed. On initial controller initialization & on page reloads. Feed data binds and renders in the view.

Problem:

- Data does not render in the view when:

  1. Any in site navigation - using for example `ui-sref('home.feed')`
  2. Feature behavior that redirects back to `state('home.feed')`. i.e. upload pic feature:

     - after file input(select file/image) image previews in add-picture state
     - add-picture state has upload feature. which then redirects back to home feed.

controller code

```
function HomeController(currenAuth, feeds) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.pixData = [];


    ///// Controller activation

    activate();


    function activate() {
        if (currentAuth) {
            getHomeFeed();
        }
    }


    ///// Controller methods

    function getHomeFeed() {
        return feeds.showHomeFeed().then((results) => {
            if (results) {
                hideNoPostsContainer();
                return vm.pixData = results[0];
            }
        });
    }

}
```

- **vm.pixData is used in the ng-repeat in the view**

Trying to figure out the best practice pattern. To ensure rendering of the data.

Other options to add as I see it are:

1. $rootscope.$on('$statechangesuccess', ...
2. resolve property in the routes config

Researching this, there is no definitive info about it. Read an article by John Papa [route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs](https://johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/). In that article, it mentions alludes to use either resolve or the activation pattern in the controller that I am using. But no suggestion to use both.

**UPDATE**

Using the resolve property seems to be the definitive way to go.

Using pattern from this [toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/](https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/) it seems to be working without a hitch so far, **but when would you want to use promise code directly in the controller?**

**Not sure why you would never not want to use the resolve property?**

router config code

```
.state('home.feed', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    content: {
                        templateUrl: 'app/spaPages/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController',
                        controllerAs: 'hc',
                        resolve: {
                            'currentAuth': ['$firebaseAuth', ($firebaseAuth) => {
                                return $firebaseAuth().$waitForSignIn();
                            }],
                            '_pixData': ['feeds', (feeds) => {
                                return feeds.showHomeFeed().then((results) => {
                                    if (results) {
                                        console.log('called from router resolve');
                                        return results[0];
                                    }
                                });
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

controller code

```
.controller('HomeController', HomeController);

function HomeController(currenAuth, _pixData) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.pixData = _pixData;
}
```

Comment: show code for `feeds.showHomeFeed()` as well as data structure being sent. Need to see what that function returns

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. the function returns an array of data - typical ng-repeat data. The data is being returned That is not the issue as I see it. Wanted to try to keep the question clean. The issue for me is an angular pattern I can take away and use consistently. Just used this pattern from todd motto article and it seems to working consistently even on scenarios I mentioned I was having issues. https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/

Comment: correction/clarification ~from above  _'the issue for me is an angular pattern I can take away and use consistently'_   expounding on it. _That renders in all scenarios_, ie. navigating away and back to the view, &/or  feature like an upload view redirects to feed view using **state.go()**

Comment: well it will based on resolve...so long as request succeeds. You also have to consider error handling...for when resolve gets reject for any reason

Comment: Yes, that was my instinctual concern is to pollute or have to right controller like code in the the resolve property. I think that was my reservation overall and still have. But at this point i am not sure another pattern that works. Weird that it is not talked about more. Maybe I am missing somthing

Comment: all depends on behavior you want and how you want to handle errors. In some instances you may want to go to controller and do something with errors there and things like `404` might have an internal redirect. A lot is dependent on app

Comment: @charlietfl  :) the only real behavior I want(need to expect) is consistent binding/rendering of data in when using a promise convention - when visiting that route.

Comment: Well you have the promises... if they suceed all's good...you have to plan your error handling based on those promises...that's the behavior I'm talking about...error handling behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as far as the original issue of not being able render promise data on route changes

At this point can be considered answered.

Using the resolve property works.

But still wondering whether what the best pattern is or best practice patterns for promise resolution and clean angular development. May be will repose the question later.